# Pandas groupby split by NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have one question, I ask you guys

I want to split the df like grp1, grp2, grp3, grp4

The data below is a sample and I really need to process a large amount of data, so please let me know how to do it appropriately.

```
df = 
                            A1     B1
    2021-03-18 00:00:00     10     23
    2021-03-18 00:00:01     11     28 
    2021-03-18 00:00:02     12     29
    2021-03-18 00:00:03     NaN    NaN
    2021-03-18 00:00:04     NaN    NaN
    2021-03-18 00:00:05     42     32
    2021-03-18 00:00:06     51     90 
    2021-03-18 00:00:07     NaN    NaN
    2021-03-18 00:00:08     90     101
    2021-03-18 00:00:09     32     42
    2021-03-18 00:00:10     NaN    NaN
    2021-03-18 00:00:11     575    333
    2021-03-18 00:00:12     62     421
```

```
grp1 =
                              A1     B1
      2021-03-18 00:00:00     10     23
      2021-03-18 00:00:01     11     28 
      2021-03-18 00:00:02     12     29
```

```
grp2 =
                              A1     B1
      2021-03-18 00:00:05     42     32
      2021-03-18 00:00:06     51     90
```

```
grp3 =
                              A1     B1
      2021-03-18 00:00:08     90     101
      2021-03-18 00:00:09     32     42
```

```
grp4 =
                              A1     B1
      2021-03-18 00:00:11     575    333
      2021-03-18 00:00:12     62     421
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
x = (df.shift(1).isnull() & df.notnull()).cumsum()['B1']
df_list = []
for i,g in df.groupby(x):
    print(i,g.dropna())
    df_list.append(g.dropna())
```

---

```
1                        A1    B1
2021-03-18 00:00:00  10.0  23.0
           00:00:01  11.0  28.0
           00:00:02  12.0  29.0
2                        A1    B1
2021-03-18 00:00:05  42.0  32.0
           00:00:06  51.0  90.0
3                        A1     B1
2021-03-18 00:00:08  90.0  101.0
           00:00:09  32.0   42.0
4                         A1     B1
2021-03-18 00:00:11  575.0  333.0
           00:00:12   62.0  421.0
```

`df_list` will have all your grouped dataframe.